# Way to limit number of records a user can create in Amplify GraphQL API

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I have an app where Auth is implemented using Cognito User Pools and API is a GraphQL API implemented using Amplify. In the Schema definitions, is there an easy way to limit the number of records a user can create. For example in the following schema...

```
type Product @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
}
```

I would like to limit the users to a maximum of 100 Products.

One way is via my front-end. When I detect that a user has reached 100 limit, I can just make the UI stop giving them the ability to add more. But if someone were to bypass the UI, they could create more than 100. Hence, I prefer to enforce this limit in the backend.

Is there a way to do this in the Schema definition, or elsewhere in AWS / DynamoDB ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a straightforward way to do this that I'm aware of.

Below is how I would solve this.

1. Create a @key on Product on the owner property, so that you can query by owner.
2. Overwrite the CreateProduct mutation. In your custom resolver, before creating a new Product, query the Product table byOwner, using the owner id passed in, to count how many already exist.
   Here is the documentation: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/resolvers#add-a-custom-geolocation-search-resolver-that-targets-an-elasticsearch-domain-created-by-searchable

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution would be processing the API request in a lambda function that validates the request (product count < 100) before having the script write to the DB.  Then you can null out the built-in mutations for the model to prevent unintended access.

**Example Schema:**

```
type Mutation {
  addProduct(input: ProductAddInput): ProductAddOutput @function(name: "productLambda-${env}")
}
type Product 
  @model(queries: null, mutations: null, subscriptions: null) /* update these to what you need */
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
}
```

In Lambda you can pull the username from the `event.identity` property and that should correlate to the owner field in the db.  Since the AWS package is automatically loaded you should be looking at very fast script execution as long as your db indexes are set properly.

For the user product count, I see a couple of options:

- A secondary index set up on the owner field so you don't do a ton of
  scans
- If you have a user table, you could add a field that counts
  the products for each user and just update that table any time you
  update the product table.